# Normal Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Let Z1 and Z2 be independent standard normal random variables. What is the probability that the minimum of Z1 and Z2 will be greater than 1.0?

How do I go about this when I have no values? Is the only reason that these can be greater than 1 because they're independent?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  The minimum will be greater than $1$ if and only if $Z_1>1$ and $Z_2>1$.  And the random variables are independent, so. . . ?

Comment: So there's 100% probability if they're greater than 1, but how do I know if they're greater than 1 or not?

Comment: They are not fixed numbers, they are **random variables**.  There is a certain **probability** that they will be greater than $1$ and a certain probability that they won't.  If you have not yet studied random variables you need to find some information about the topic and then come back to this question.

Comment: Well I know that f(x)=1 when x is between 0 and 1 and f(x)=0 otherwise, then their minimum has to be greater than 1 no matter what. I this on the right track? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is not a standard normal random variable, it is a different kind of random variable.  Sorry but you need to grab your textbook/lecture notes/whatever, and really go back to basics on this.

Comment: After reading some more, it seems like the probability of Zi and Z2 can't be the same, meaning that they can't both equal 1 at the same time, so the probability would be zero.